# for-in loops don't discriminate the classes?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a custom UIButton subclass. A lot of them actually.

So I wanted to enumerate thru all of them in my containerView.subviews in a for-in loop.
But when I run it like so:

```
for (CustomButton *button in self.containerView.subviews)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", button.class);
}
```

...the first object that gets iterated is a UIImageView that is also a subview. Why doesn't the for-in loop only give me the class I wanted?

Comment: Why should it give you only `CustomButton` subclasses?

Comment: Note that dealing with the UI by futzing with the view hierarchy directly is generally Very Bad Design.   It is fragile and a maintenance headache.

Comment: It was testing code. It wasn't final code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will iterate through all the objects in array and try to cast to CustomButton class. You need to do some filtering:

```
for (CustomButton *button in self.containerView.subview)
{
    if ([button isKindOfClass: [CustomButton class]])
       NSLog(@"%@", button.class);
}
```

Comment: `self.containerView.subview` gives an array of `UIView`, not `CustomButton`. The for-loop variable should either be `id` or `UIView`.

Answer (score 2):

The for-in loop does exactly what it is supposed to do. It iterates through all subviews of the container view (of your cell or scroll view?).

You could process them recursively so that you go through all subviews of the subviews, if any, in the same manner. 
At least that is what I would do.

And then you check the class type (using isKindOfClass) and process only those where you are interested in.

You'd be surprised to see how many subviews a button may have.

Edit: There is one more aspect of your question that I haven't addressed so far. You ask for the "discrimination" for the for-in loop. It is not an aspect of the loop. For-in simple iterates though all elements of an container. That may be an array, dictionary or set. In your sample you just typecast each object into CustomButton type object.
Doing so the compiler will pass without error even if you access a property or method that is unique to your Custom Button. Then an exception will be thrown on runtime.

Comment: I was just misinformed about how it worked. I thought it would only enumerate thru the objects that were already cast as the class I wanted. I didn't realize it was would give me all elements!